# How can I create an owl:intersectionOf two owl:Classes?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, rdfs

For a school exercise, I have an RDF file and an OWL file.

There is an `owl:Class Lecturer` and an `owl:Class Researcher`. The intersection of both should be a Professor. I have put my RDF and OWL file below.

Problem is: when I do my query, no resource is of type Professor, while in the RDF file we can see that Laura should be a Professor.

Reduced version of rdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY humans   "http://www.inria.fr/2007/09/11/humans.rdfs"> 
<!ENTITY xsd      "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"> ]> 
<rdf:RDF  
   xmlns:rdf ="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
   xmlns:xsd ="&xsd;" 
   xmlns     ="&humans;#" 
   xml:base  ="&humans;-instances" > 
    <Person rdf:ID="Laura">
        <name>Laura</name>
    </Person>
    <Lecturer rdf:about="#Laura"/>
    <Researcher rdf:about="#Laura">
      <name>Laura</name>
    </Researcher>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Reduced version of owl file:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xml:base="http://www.inria.fr/2007/09/11/humans.rdfs"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Person">
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Lecturer">
        <subClassOf rdf:resource="#Person"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Researcher">
        <subClassOf rdf:resource="#Person"/>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:id="Professor">
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <owl:Class rdf:about="#Lecturer"/>
            <owl:Class rdf:about="#Researcher"/>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
    </owl:Class>

</rdf:RDF>
```

The query I used was the defautl query:

```
 select * where {
   ?x ?p ?y
 }
```

But what I actually would expect to do is the following:

```
select * where {
   ?x a <http://www.inria.fr/2007/09/11/humans.rdfs#Professor>
}
```

I did look at this answer: [Why do we need to use rdf:parseType="Collection" with owl:intersectionOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947796/why-do-we-need-to-use-rdfparsetype-collection-with-owlintersectionof) but I don't understand in which way it should be used for my specific problem.

I hope somebody can help. By the way, it's my first post here, so let me know if something's missing.

Comment: I hope you understand that SPARQL primarily does only triple pattern matching on RDF. Your data does **not** contain any individual that is used in a triple (resp. OWL class assertion axiom) stating that it belongs to the class `Professor`. Anything beyond triple matching needs so-called reasoning, i.e. inferring implicit data.

Comment: Either you use some SPARQL engine that supports reasoning, or you use some alternative query mechanism like DL Query. Note, both of which are totally different indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AKSW Indeed my rdf data does not say that the resource is assigned to Professor. But it does state that the resource is a Lecturer and a Researcher. So using the owl schema (which specifies that a Professor is anyone who is both Lecturer and Researcher) in addition to the rdf data, I thought I should be able to do a query for all Professors and still retreive my resource (Laura).  I am using the Corese SPARQL engine (http://wimmics.inria.fr/corese). Are you saying this approach is impossible?

Comment: Use `<owl:Class rdf:ID="Professor">` instead of `<owl:Class rdf:id="Professor">`. I have loaded your RDF files into GraphDB triplestore with "OWL-Max" reasoning, Laura really is a Professor.

Comment: @StanislavKralin your answer contains the solution: I was not aware of the query engine containing several options for the types of reasoning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoosKorstanje, I hope that OWL RL Corese ["engine"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwX2K.png) will give you what you want: [1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/#OWL2RLDS), [2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL).

Comment: @JoosKorstanje I know that Laura belongs to both. Both that doesn't matter for the SPARQL engine. You're inferring that she must belong to class Professor, and exactly this rule-based thing of your mind has to be enabled in the SPARQL engine (if exist). Without, it can only match the data that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrased from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316549/how-can-i-create-an-owlintersectionof-two-owlclasses#comment79598420_46316549) by @[stanislav-kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin):

Use correct capitalization of `rdf:ID` (not `rdf:id`), and enable "OWL-Max" reasoning when loading your RDF into GraphDB.